# Set memory_limit to PHP FPM with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fpm, mod-php

I need to modify in the htaccess the memory_limit,
max_input_vars and max_execution_time of php.
In order not to modify the global configuration of php on the server.

In my virtualhost, I have this configuration:

```
<FilesMatch \.php> 
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/" 
</FilesMatch>
```

In my htaccess I have tested these two configs without success:

```
<IfModule php7_module>
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
    php_value max_execution_time 1800
</IfModule>
```

And

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value max_input_vars 10000
    php_value max_execution_time 1800
</IfModule>
```

In the case of `php7.3-fpm.sock`, do I have to use it another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

php-fpm and mod-php are two different ways to use php with an apache webserver.
The .htaccess rules only work with mod-php. The IfModule rule ensures that they are only executed if mod-php is in use.
In both cases you can use the php function set_time_limit(1800) and ini_set('memory_limit', '512M') in your PHP-code to change the time- and memory-limits (if allowed by the server config).

Answer (score 1):

in your configuration file, default path "/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/php7.3-fpm.conf" or your path, change to:

```
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = 10000
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 1800
```

then restart your web service, and test your settings.

Comment: Hi @kleber-holtz, Thank you for your response.
The thing is that I don't have to touch any system file, only htaccess.
If it were global, I would have done it already. Thank you in any case

Comment: Okay, your syntax via htaccess is correct, the problem is with the interpreter.